# Adding several banners over each other

Tags: ios, admob, iad

Can we add multiple banners over each other within the same view controller?
It's technically possible, but is it legal for us to add several AdMob or iAd banners over each other in the same view controller so we can earn more money?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible, yes. Will it make you more money, no. The revenue generated per an impression of an ad is a fraction of the revenue generated per a tap on an ad. In addition, the iAd network will not like your app requesting numerous ads repeatedly and will in turn lower your fill rate. I would imagine AdMob has similar safeguards in place to avoid scenarios like this. As far as legal, I'm sure it would violate both Apple's and Google's TOS if you were to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You will get yourself kicked out of the Admob program permanently really quickly.

- It's against Googles Terms of Service.
- You earn money for clicks, not ad displays.
- Google can detect this. They know what the click through rate for apps and ads should be. If your app displays 8 times as many ads as anybody else or more clicks or less clicks, their automated computers will detect it and you will be kicked out, no money for you. Don't mess with Google - if you are kicked out there is no way back in. It is permanent.